# Update Status of Customer on the basis of 12 month difference when there are Multiple Items in the Order ID

Tags: mysql, logic

I want to Check for each Customer based on Brands whether He/She is a first time Buyer or Recurring Buyer. If Customer has ordered product for the first time or is ordering after 12 Months -They are First time buyer else Recurring.

Challenge is There are Multiple Items in Single Order Id and I have Tried LAG() Function to get previous date , But LAG() is giving previous date same as order date From 2nd item Id till Nth Item for the same Order Id.

Because of Which Difference cannot be calculated Correctly , I have Tried Ranking as well and LAG() function in Case When Statements But not getting positive Results.

My Intention here is to get Last order date of- Last order id, Irrespective of how many item ID's are pooled in Single order id. - So that I can get Previous order date correctly.

My Code is -

```
with cte as (
select distinct
    A.brand,
    A.[Item Id],
    A.[Order Id],
    A.[Customer Id],
    cast(left(A.[Order Date],10) as date) as order_date
        
from ldg.ShippedSales A
)
,cte2 as (
    select brand,
        [Item Id],
        [Order Id],
        [Customer Id],
        order_date,
        year(order_date) as year,
        min(order_date) over (partition by [customer id] , brand) as first_purchase_date,
        LAG([order_date]) over(partition by [customer id],brand order by order_date) as Previous_order_date
    from cte
    where len([Customer Id]) >1
)
,cte3 as (
    select *
        , DATEDIFF(MONTH,previous_order_date,order_date) as Month_diff
        , DATEDIFF(Day,previous_order_date,order_date) as Day_diff
    from cte2
         )
,cte4 as
    (   
    select *
        ,case when month_diff is null or month_diff>12 then 'First' else 'Repeating'
            end as Order_type_month
        ,row_number() over(partition by  brand ,[customer id],[order id]    order by   order_date,[order id]) as Recurring_rank
    from cte3
    )
    
    
    select *,
    case when month_diff is null or month_diff>12  then  'First Time'
        when lag(Order_type_month) over (partition by brand ,[customer id] order by order_date) = 'first' and recurring_rank >1 then 'First Time'
            else  'Recurring' end as new_logic
    from cte4
```

[Please click here for OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz5iO.png)
Please refer from Row 2 to 4 where Previous date are coming same as order date coz of that Difference is 0 hence Logic is not working. I have Tried LAG() in CASE WHEN() as well but it is not working when there are more than 2 items in first time purchase.

Please Download Sample File and Expected Output from - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/748230496f267cfaea0bdcb3c7cd22a620221020134422/276cdf

Comment: mysql and SQL Server are two different RDBMS. Which one do you use ? Please delete unnable tag

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags for now. As mentioned, [edit] your question to (re)tag the appropriate (R)DBMS.

Comment: Please provide sample data and your expected output. Don't post screenshots of data, its hard to work with.

Comment: @GRIV please check the links I have updated the information , Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @PalashTiwari, I appreciate you trying to provide sample data but you should provide the data **here** for convenience sake and only the minimal amount to reproduce and demonstrate your issue. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).